# Aspectj advice not getting executed

Tags: spring-mvc, aspectj

I am trying to code a simple AspectJ implementation but the Advice is not getting executed.

The LoggingAspect Class is getting initiated  as in the console I can see s.o.p of constructor

```
This is logging aspect
```

getting printed when the ApplicationContext is loaded and controllerAspect is initialized. When I run the main method , the output is

```
Name: John Age :12
```

What I was expecting was the s.o.p for @Before advice should be printed first and then for getter methods @AfterReturning s.o.p should be printed.

There is no compilation error , the program is running but advice is not  getting executed.

According to the pointcut, the advice should get implemented on all methods of the Customer class.

I went through some of the similar problems posted here , but could not figure out what was the issue with my implementation.

Can any one figure the mistake I am making and provide the resolution ?

Here is the snippet  servlet-context.xml

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="main.com.controller"/>                
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven></annotation-driven>      

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<!-- AOP support -->      

<bean id='controllerAspect' class='main.com.logging.LoggingAspect' />
<beans:bean id="cust" class="main.com.dtos.Customer"</beans:bean> 

<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">       
<beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
<beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</beans:bean>
```

The LoggingAspect class is :

```java
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
    public LoggingAspect() {
        System.out.println("This is logging aspect");
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.dtos.*.*(..))")
    public void getMethodPointcut() {}

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "getMethodPointcut()", returning="retVal")
    public void afterReturningAdvice(Object retVal) {
        System.out.println("Returning:" + retVal.toString() );
    }

    @Before("getMethodPointcut()")
    public void printBefore(JoinPoint jp ) {
        System.out.println("Before calling method:"+jp.getSignature());
}
```

Customer class is :

```java
@Size(max=30, min=3)
@NotNull
private String name;

@Max(150)
@NotNull
private String age; 

public Customer() {}

public Customer(String sName, String sAge) {
    name = sName;
    age = sAge;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Customer [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
}
```

Main method is :

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = 
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:servlet- context.xml");

    Customer cust = (Customer)context.getBean("cust");
    cust.setAge("12");
    cust.setName("John");

    String name = cust.getName();
    String age = cust.getAge();

    System.out.println("Name: "+name+" Age :"+age);
}
```

Aspectj POM dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The most important part is missing in your code snippet: What is the package name of  `Customer`? Your Spring config implies it is `main.com.dtos.Customer`, your aspect pointcut is looking for `com.dtos.*` (without `main.` prefix) though.

Comment: The package is `main.com.dtos.` Thanks for pointing out , I changed the pointcut to `execution(* main.com.dtos.Customer.get*())` and it worked.

Comment: Sorry about the indentation , the block formatting was missed.

Answer (score 0):

Just so as to enable you to close the question by accepting an answer, I am repeating my answer from the comment:

Your Spring config implies it is `main.com.dtos.Customer`, your aspect pointcut is looking for `com.dtos.*` (without `main.` prefix) though.